# How to smooth the table plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, smooth

I need to smooth these two corners. I want to make chemical acidimetry graph. Now it looks like this:

[image]

and I need to have something more like this:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin={[normalized]-1.7},
minor tick num=1,
grid = minor,
grid style={ultra thin, dashed, gray!50},
xmin=0, xmax=25, ymin=0, ymax=14,
xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25}, ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
xlabel={$V_{{tit}}~\mathrm{(cm^3)}$}, ylabel={pH}]
\addplot [blue,name path=B,smooth] table {
x       y
0       13
2.5         12.85
5       12.7
7.5         12.5
10      12.3
12.1        12.1
12.5        7
12.8        2.7
15      2.5
17.5        2.35
20      2.15
22.5        2.05
25      2
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't know much about chemistry. That said, as an approximation I'd look for functions like

```
y=a+b*log(c±x)
```

and then we can find the constants a,b,c using some points of the plot (equilibrium point, initial and final value, some other data from your table,...)

Something like this (that probably will need more tweaking):

```
\documentclass[border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=1,
grid = minor,
grid style={ultra thin, dashed, gray!50},
xmin=0, xmax=25, ymin=0, ymax=14,
xtick={0,5,...,25}, ytick={0,2,...,14},
xlabel={$V_{\text{tit}}$ (\unit{cm^3})}, ylabel={pH}]
\addplot [blue,smooth] table {
x       y
0       13
2.5     12.85
5       12.7
7.5     12.5
10      12.3
12.1    12.1
12.5     7
12.8     2.7
15       2.5
17.5     2.35
20       2.15
22.5     2.05
25       2
};
\addplot[red,thick,samples=100,domain=0:12.5004] {11.05+1.78*log10(12.51-\x};
\addplot[red,thick,samples=100,domain=12.4996:25] {3.95-1.78*log10(\x-12.49};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's amazing, thank you very much. But can I ask how did you find the constants a,b,c ?

Comment: @MichałSzymankiewicz I don't have the numbers, but as I said, put some data into the equation and then solve the equation system. Example: with (0,13) you'll have 13=1+b*log(c-0), and so on

Comment: Ok, thanks again :D